# Silverlight for Windows Phone: BindingExpression path error with user control - Property not found

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, data-binding, mvvm, mvvm-light

Just hit a very odd issue with databinding which I cannot seem to get to the bottom of:

Scenario
An MVVM View model data bound to a parent form with two properties

```
    public RelayCommand ClearFilteredCategories { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="ClearFilterText" /> property's name.
    /// </summary>
    public const string ClearFilterTextPropertyName = "ClearFilterText";

    private string _clearFilterText = "Clear Filter";

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets and gets the ClearFilterText property.
    /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
    /// </summary>
    public string ClearFilterText
    {
        get
        {
            return _clearFilterText;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_clearFilterText == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _clearFilterText = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(ClearFilterTextPropertyName);
        }
    }
```

Then I have a User control with Two dependency Properties, thus:

```
    public partial class ClearFilterButton : UserControl
{
    public ClearFilterButton()
    {
        // Required to initialize variables
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string ClearFilterString
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ClearFilterStringProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ClearFilterStringProperty, value); }
    }

    public RelayCommand ClearFilterAction
    {
        get { return (RelayCommand)GetValue(ClearFilterActionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ClearFilterActionProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ClearFilterStringProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ClearFilterString", typeof(string), typeof(ClearFilterButton), new PropertyMetadata("", ClearFilterString_PropertyChangedCallback));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ClearFilterActionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ClearFilterAction", typeof(RelayCommand), typeof(ClearFilterButton), new PropertyMetadata(null, ClearFilterAction_PropertyChangedCallback));

    private static void ClearFilterString_PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //empty
    }

    private static void ClearFilterAction_PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //empty
    }
}
```

and User Control XAML:

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity" xmlns:GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WP71"
mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Class="ATTCookBook.ClearFilterButton"
d:DesignWidth="75" d:DesignHeight="75"
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Width="75" Height="75">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                <GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ClearFilterAction, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush Stretch="UniformToFill" ImageSource="/icons/appbar.refresh.rest.png"/>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,8" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ClearFilterString, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="13.333" Height="18" Width="0" d:LayoutOverrides="VerticalAlignment"/>
</Grid>
```

Now when I add this User Control to the Main Page and databind the two View Model Properties through to the User control it gets very weird:

```
<local:ClearFilterButton Height="Auto" Width="Auto" ClearFilterAction="{Binding ClearFilteredCategories, Mode=TwoWay}" ClearFilterString="{Binding ClearFilterText, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Because although the Databinding statements above seem fine, the Binding errors with:

> System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'ClearFilteredCategories' property not found on 'ATTCookBook.ClearFilterButton' 'ATTCookBook.ClearFilterButton' (HashCode=126600431). BindingExpression: Path='ClearFilteredCategories' DataItem='ATTCookBook.ClearFilterButton' (HashCode=126600431); target element is 'ATTCookBook.ClearFilterButton' (Name=''); target property is 'ClearFilterAction' (type 'GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command.RelayCommand')..
>
> System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'ClearFilterText' property not found on 'ATTCookBook.ClearFilterButton' 'ATTCookBook.ClearFilterButton' (HashCode=126600431). BindingExpression: Path='ClearFilterText' DataItem='ATTCookBook.ClearFilterButton' (HashCode=126600431); target element is 'ATTCookBook.ClearFilterButton' (Name=''); target property is 'ClearFilterString' (type 'System.String')..

Which seems to indicate the View Model is trying to find the parent properties in the child user control?
I do not understand why this could be because I have set a Relative Data Context within the child user control to avoid this and the binding should be passing through the two dependency properties.

I was hoping to make the user control more generic later but cannot seem to even get it working in a basic fashion

Quick call out to you Silverlight Binding masters :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved in the end with some thanks to the above, however the answer was a lot simpler.

All I had to do was remove any mention of Modes (remove Mode="TwoWay") and remove the DataContext setting from the user control and it just worked.

Just goes to show it's very easy to over-engineer a solution.

I Suspect by adding the Mode setting it was trying to pass the datacontext through the binding and that what it was throwing up (not a very helpful error message)

Hope this helps others.  Just keep it simple and work up from there.

For those that are interested, I was basing the implementation from this very useful post - [Silverlight UserControl Custom Property Binding](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/133665.aspx/1)

Answer (score 0):

In your UserControl you are resetting the Datacontext so now the expression

```
ClearFilterAction="{Binding ClearFilteredCategories, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

is not relative to the Page where you are using the UserControl but to the UserControl itself. You can encounter the same problem with ItemTemplate datacontext when you want to reference a common command declared on the VM of the Page and not on the object data bound to the template.

You can use a proxy:

```
ClearFilterAction="{Binding Source={StaticResource 
DataContextProxy},Path=DataSource.ClearFilteredCategories}"
```

The proxy is declared as a Resource:

```
<Resources:DataContextProxy x:Key="DataContextProxy" />
```

and the code of the DataProxy class:

```
public class DataContextProxy : FrameworkElement
{
    public DataContextProxy()
    {
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(DataContextProxy_Loaded);
    }

    void DataContextProxy_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var binding = new Binding();
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(BindingPropertyName))
        {
            binding.Path = new PropertyPath(BindingPropertyName);
        }
        binding.Source = this.DataContext;
        binding.Mode = BindingMode;
        this.SetBinding(DataContextProxy.DataSourceProperty, binding);
    }

    public Object DataSource
    {
        get { return (Object)GetValue(DataSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("DataSource", typeof(Object), typeof(DataContextProxy), null);


    public string BindingPropertyName { get; set; }

    public BindingMode BindingMode { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the assignment of the data context to usercontrol's root `DataGrid`.

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity" xmlns:GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WP71"
mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Class="ATTCookBook.ClearFilterButton"
d:DesignWidth="75" d:DesignHeight="75">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" DataContext="{Binding Parent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" >
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Width="75" Height="75">
```